# How to change dynamically the index of JavaScript file according to eventlistener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I am using the following code to get the answers and questions of json file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("data.json", function (json) {
        var anserFor1st = json.questions[0].answers;
        var anserFor2nd = json.questions[1].answers; //If it's more than two use a loop
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(anserFor1st) + "<br/>" + JSON.stringify(anserFor2nd);
        var aString = "";
        Object.keys(anserFor1st).forEach(function (k) {
            aString += anserFor1st[k] + "<br/>";
        });
        Object.keys(anserFor2nd).forEach(function (k) {
            aString += anserFor2nd[k] + "<br/>";
        });
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = aString;
    });
});
```

Instead I want to change dynamically the index of the answers&question, aka write the following:

```
var anser = json.questions[i].answers;
```

I have to change the index according to event-listener to clicking next and forward buttons in the html file.

How do I change the index dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean you want this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("data.json", function (json) {
        var answers = [];
        var aString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < json.questions.length; i++)
        {
            answers[i] = json.questions[i].answers;
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(answers[i]) + "<br/>";
            for (var j = 0; j < answers[i].length; j++)
            {
                aString += answers[i][j] + "<br/>";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = aString;
    });
});
```

This code does exactly what yours did, but there are some things in there that make no sense (such as first loading the `json.questions[i].answers` into the content element, only to then replace it a few lines later with the contents of `aString`.) You also stringify the JSON before placing it into the DOM, but I'd have expected you to do the opposite (parsing it, since you already just retrieved it as JSON, so stringifying it again shouldn't do anything).

Basically, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by your question, so if I misunderstood please clarify your question.

EDIT: if your problem is just remembering which question you're on, make a variable to hold the number of the current question (e.g. `var currentQuestion = 1;`), and then just change that based on what button is clicked.

For example:

```
$("#buttonPrevious").on("click", function (e)
{
    currentQuestion--;
});
$("#buttonNext").on("click", function (e)
{
    currentQuestion++;
});
```

Of course you can check for minimum/maximum question numbers (for example, your max number of questions can be equal to the last value of `i` in the loop above).

Comment: where I have to put the script of the buttons?

Comment: @Sara Anywhere you want, as long as the buttons have been loaded into the DOM when your script executes. I'll make a JSFiddle to demonstrate. Could you post an example JSON string?

Comment: @Sara Sorry it took a while, first I made a silly mistake which I had to track down (mis-wrote my manual JSON), then the entire internet connection dropped. But here is the working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WBison/g5ms6nve/4/

Comment: the example does not match what I asked. The content of the question supposed to be changed. For example at first question1 is displayed. Only after I press Next question 2 will be displayed.

Comment: Here is example for json :  {
    "questions": [
        {
            "question#1": "How much is 3+1",
            "correct answer": 1,
            "answers": {
                "ans#1": "5",
                "ans#2": "4",
                "ans#3": "3"
            }
        },
 {
            "question#5": "How much is 2+4",
            "correct answer": 0,
            "answers": {
                "ans#1": "6",
                "ans#2": "4",
                "ans#3": "7",
                "ans#4": "5"
            }
        }

    ]
}